# How to add the [pifont] option to the spacingtricks package documentation

Tags: optional-arguments, pifont

For the novice TeX programmer such as I, package documentation such as that for the **spacingtricks package** is akin to the Bible, particularly when it comes to specifying all package options.

I recently updated the **spacingtricks package** via TeX Live Utility and suddenly the presence of a few aliases in my code such as the `\hand` and `\arrowsymb` resulted in multiple undefined errors.

Upon consulting the **spacingtricks** documentation, the '**Usage**' introduction made no reference to *any* options. However, the undefined error would not disappear.

I imagine that for the vast majority of TeX programmers, this would be a no brainer, as the text on page 5 of the documentation (not page 1) clearly made a reference that:

> Some other common symbols can be found in the pifont package [9]. Therefore spacingtricks has a **pifont** option, that loads this package and creates the appropriate aliases:

Silly me, but it took me several minutes (I actually don't want to say how long ...) to read the text and realize that I needed to add `[pifont]` as an option to the:
 `\usepackage{spacingtricks}` to become `\usepackage[pifont]{spacingtricks}` in my Setup even though I had already separately included `\usepackage{pifont}` elsewhere in my Setup.

In perhaps a vain attempt to save other novice TeX programmers from a bothersome waste of time, I am wondering if it may be possible to somehow prompt the **spacingtricks** documentation to include a brief note as part of the introduction to explicitly state what is obvious to most, e.g. to add `[pifont]` to `\usepackage{spacingtricks}` to become `\usepackage[pifont]{spacingtricks}`?

Apologies to the vast majority of TeX programmers who would have understood the need to add the `[pifont]` option in less than a split second and would have been on their way w/o having a second thought.

Despite the delay, I'm looking forward to adding a few additional features that are provided by the **spacingtricks package** ... such as  the `\begin{compactlist}[\checksymb]`, `\begin{indentblock}\itshape` and `\centered{⟨text⟩}` features.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Well the package documentation shows the author email,  so you could write to them. Generally I would be wary with packages like this which define and redefine lots of things. They easily clash with other package or even with changes in latex itself.

Comment: Another way would be to post a self-answered question here on the site. People that face the same issue may try to find the answer in the manual but they are also likely to search online for a particular error. If they find this self-answered question then that could save them the time that you spent finding it out. Of course it would not be sensible to ask self-answered questions on each option of every package, but if a manual is rather unclear and the issue concerns core functionality/commands of a package then it may be a good idea.

Comment: A self-answered question can be: Question When using the `\hand`, `\checksymb` and `\arrowsymb` commands from the `spacingtricks` package I get undefined control sequence errors. Here is a reproducible example including a documentclass, `\usepackage{spacingtricks}`, begin/end document and a `compactlist`: [insert full example document]. Answer: as mentioned somewhat cryptically in the manual on page 5 (quote from and link to manual), you should load the `pifonts` package, either separately with `\usepackage{pifonts}` or as a package option with `\usepackage[pifonts]{spacingtricks}`.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer - Thank you ... I will forward a copy of my post to the author listed ... Re your comment on `packages like this which define and redefine lots of things`,  I am actually a bit surprised at a few of the options offered by the package, and will keep your thought in mind as to `They easily clash with other package or even with changes in latex itself.`

Comment: @Marijn - Thank you for the proforma `self-answered question` suggestion ... As a novice, I use SE sparingly, so your comment is appreciated. I was a bit hesitant to post anything about the documentation as I realize that so much of what is available via LaTeX is gratis, and so *any* documentation is a gift, and any *feedback* risks appearing ungrateful. The `spacingtricks` package has already provided benefits (given the caveat offered by @Ulrike Fischer) so I am grateful for the functions it provides, option and all.

Comment: @RosesBouquet I understand your sentiment about feedback to package authors, however you can also regard feedback/clarifications to the documentation as a service to the community. By extension the package author also profits from this because increasing the amount of (useful) information about a package makes the package easier to use, which may in turn lead to more people using the package and more recognition for the author.

Comment: For example, before I saw your question I did not know that the package existed, and now I have read the manual and I know something about the goals and approaches of the package, thanks to you asking about it.